Remove Insert Image from CLEditor html js
I am using  CLEditor WYSIWYG HTML Editor v1.4.5 , for all the text area support but now I want to remove Insert Image option and hide it, please suggest the approach
I want to know if there is any configuration can be used to hide those fields
